# How to list Shared Photo Stream Albums with PhotoKit

Tags: ios, ios8, icloud, photokit

I can obtain a list of Photo Albums created on the device with `PHFetchResult *results = [PHCollectionList fetchTopLevelUserCollectionsWithOptions:nil];`

I imagine there must be a similar way to obtain Shared Photo Streams Albums (or as I think they may be called now "iCloud Photo Sharing Albums"), but for the life of me...can't figure it out. Has anyone solved this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PhotoKit's querying logic confuses the hell out me, but here is the answer below works for me (hint: you have to query a `PHAssetCollection`, not a `PHCollectionList`)

`PHFetchResult *results = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:PHAssetCollectionTypeAlbum subtype:PHAssetCollectionSubtypeAlbumCloudShared options:nil]`

Comment: can i get cloudOwner name who shared this album?

Answer (score 3):

For those looking for the swift syntax:

```
let result = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: PHAssetCollectionType.album, subtype: PHAssetCollectionSubtype.albumCloudShared, options: nil)

result.enumerateObjects { (phassetcollection, index, setThisToTrueToStop) in
    print("\(index): \(phassetcollection.localizedTitle)  \(phassetcollection.localIdentifier)")
}
```

Comment: Recent Swift syntax: ```let result = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: PHAssetCollectionType.album, subtype: PHAssetCollectionSubtype.albumCloudShared, options: nil);
  result.enumerateObjects { (phassetcollection, index, setThisToTrueToStop) in } ```

Comment: @otusweb can i get cloudOwner name who shared this album?